# Delphi Unique Dynamic Form Creation

Tags: forms, delphi, dynamic, chat, creation

I am using multiple forms on my project. (Client Server Application) I used chat but i have some problems.

1- I have a user list on my listview. And i am open new chat form here.

```
procedure CreateNewChat(User: String);
var
 ChatForm: TChatForm;
begin
 ChatForm:= TChatForm.Create(nil); 
 if assigned (ChatForm) then
  ChatForm.User:= User;
  Chat.Socket:= MySocket; // TClientSocket new Instance
  ChatForm.Show;
end;

///Chatform

procedure ParseData(Cmd:string);
begin
if Cmd <> '' then
 begin
  /// parsing...
 end;
```

New connections are adding to listview like that

```
var
  Item: TListItem;
  NewTempForm: TTempForm;
begin

  NewTempForm := tempForm.Create;
  Item := Listview.Items.Add;

  if User = '' then
    Exit;

  Item.Caption := User;
  Item.SubItems.Add('OK');
  Item.GroupId := GroupId;
  Item.SubItems.Objects[0] := NewTempForm;
end;
```

My problems are started on here.

1- How can i detect form according to user? So, if two or higher form is open then how can i show received message on them? Because i was create them dynamically. I need a object for detect.

I tryed like that

```
 var
  tempForm: TTempForm; // this is an empty object class
  sTempStr: String;
begin
  if ListView.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    tempForm := TTempForm(ListView.Selected.SubItems.Objects[0]); // this is for unique form creation
    if tempForm.frmTasks = nil then // if there is not, create!
    begin
      tempForm.frmTasks := TfrmTasks.Create(nil);
    end;
```

But my received message is appear on all forms. Actually should appear just one form. (Which user sent it)

Thanks.

Comment: `TListItem.SubItems.Objects` is OK for storing an object pointer, but I would use `TListItem.Data` instead. Either way, when you receive a message, you have to search for the `TListItem` that belongs to that user (`Selected` is not good enough) and then you can access the object(s) associated with that user.

Comment: Rather than using `TListView` for that kind of tracking, you might consider writing a `record`/`class` to keep track of per-user info, and then store that in a separate container, like `TList`/`TObjectList` or `TDictionary`. Use the `TListView` in virtual mode for displaying the available users only. Keep your UI logic separate from your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for answer Remy. I fixed it. You right. Seleted is a bad choose for me. I got ListItem object on connection and i called like this (TFormChat(LItem.SubItems.Objects[0]).Memo1.Text:= Msg).

Comment: @RemyLebeau My issue is continue now. I tryed ListView.Data but every Items are adding to last Item form.